# Клонирование приватного удаленного репозитория

Tags: git

Подскажите кто знает, не дает покоя один вопрос.

Дело в том, что с гитом работаю недавно и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Создал приватный репозиторий на bitbucket и команда git clone https://... на компе на котором я создавал репозиторий работает отлично - он клонируется, всё хорошо.

Но когда сажусь за другой комп, то команда в гите git clone https://... не работает.

При клонировании возникает ошибка аутентификации, при этом в процессе клонирования запрос на ввод логина и пароля не происходит.

Comment: Вот это курили - https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git ?

Comment: То-есть чтобы клонировать тот-же репозиторий не другом компе необходимо сперва проделать следующие команды

Comment: git init, $ git config --global user.name, $ git config --global user.email, а потом только git clone...

Comment: Нет, тем более *git init* вообще тут не нужен.

Comment: *https://* *user@site.sample.com/path/to/repo* пробовали?

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался, подобные проблемы здесь уже рассматривались
Все дело в том, что в windows git оставляет учетные записи. Например в windows10 они находятся в Панель управления -> учетные записи пользователей -> Диспетчер учетных записей. При клонировании репозитория git данные логина и пароля тенет оттуда. Если на другом компе этих данных нет то git запросит ввод логина и пароля. Если же остались какие-либо старые, то опираясь на них, при клонировании нового репозитория, в процессе авторизации возникнет ошибка.

Comment: Так как решил эту проблему?